# How to implement roles in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was create a website it runs perfectly. But I have one problem am having two folders, called  `user` and `admin`. Both folders contain a home.aspx file. Suppose you are a user, not an admin, and you have logged in using a username and password.

Given an URL like this: `http:localhost:8080/user/home.aspx`, suppose you go to addressbar and type `admin` instead of `user` means you can access the admin page with your session.

How can I block the access to the admin page for regular users?

Answer (score 3):

When logging in, you should set a flag identifying the type of user. The on each page where login is required, you check whether the currently logged in user is a type of user you want to allow access to the page.

So on admin/home.aspx, psuedo-code:

```
if (!LoggedInUser.IsAdmin)
    Redirect("Not Allowed");
```

And on user/home.aspx:

```
if (LoggedInUser == null)
    Redirect("Not Allowed");
```

There are many ways to do this, depending on the way you handle your users. An example can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest prescribed way to get started is using the ASP.net membership and roles system which allows you to define folder level permissions based upon the logged in user - and many more features.

These videos will get you started: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication

Answer (score 0):

When user(not admin) logs in, set a user role in session:

**For Example:**

set `isAdmin=false` in session

Now at beginning of admin page:

```
if( isAdmin is false ) {
   // Redirect to any other page or error page
}

// Other admin content
```

Comment: oh, did not notice that. Thanks :)